# Running (lein) REPL in VS CODE

Tags: clojure, visual-studio-code, editor, leiningen

Is there a way to use lein's REPL in VS Code? I mean, using tasks.js, or something.

I wanted an integrated enviroment to run, test and build my clojures applications. I think maybe I could achieve something like this using vs code, because it has support to third parties compilers.
I could use `lein run`, but it did not work with `lein repl`.

I've read tasks' documentation, but there's nothing related to REPL.

Here's the tasks.js code I've used:

```
{
    // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "lein",
    "tasks": 
    [
        {
            "taskName": "run",
            "showOutput": "always",
            "args": ["run"],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "isWatching": false
        },

        {
            "taskName": "repl",
            "showOutput": "always",
            "args": ["repl"],
            "isWatching": true
        }
    ],

    "isShellCommand": true
}
```

Comment: The repl isn't 'watching' in the same way that VS is using the meaning of that word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the author of [Calva](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cospaia.clojure4vscode) I can recommend it.

Seriously, at the moment it is supporting interactive programming the best. There is a short summary of what it can do in the Editors section of the `shadow-cljs` user guide: https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_calva_vs_code

Comment: Just updated the accepted answer :) Good job! Hope it will make things easier for beginners

Comment: Thanks! If anyone has suggestions/feedback please don't hesitate to chat me (`@pez`) up in the `#editors` channel of the Clojurians slack: https://clojurians.slack.com/messages/editors/ (I try to keep updated on what is going on at ClojureVerse too.)

Answer (score 4):

### Updated (July 2021)

For Clojure and ClojureScript development in VSCode, [Calva](https://calva.io/) is the recommended plugin, as it has added a lot of support.

### Original Answer (2016)

There's extension available now which you can use.

[Github](https://github.com/avli/clojureVSCode)

[VS Code Market Place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=avli.clojure)

Comment: I think this extension won't provide you with an interactive REPL atm.

Comment: But this one does: [Calva: Clojure for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cospaia.clojure4vscode)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe a real REPL is possible at the moment in VSCode.
With that being said, this is currently being worked on over here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/547

Comment: Do you think that it's possible to do some work around or that it already exists?

Comment: Some plugins already emulate a REPL by allowing to select some text, run a command to execute it, and then have the output written to an output channel. (i.e: [ionide](http://ionide.io/)) - but that's about it for now.

Comment: Sadly they closed that issue settling for using the VS Code integrated terminals and let extensions send text to the pty. It is a sort of solution, but quite far from what Cursive and Emacs Cider can offer.